# In Julia do multiple dots force same array elements count?

Tags: c#, matlab, for-loop, julia, translate

So I look at code like this [code](https://github.com/SimonDanisch/SchroedingersSmoke.jl/blob/master/src/MatlabPort.jl#L110):

```
vx = angle.(
    conj.(psi1).*view(psi1, ixp,:,:) .+
    conj.(psi2).*view(psi2, ixp,:,:)
);
```

Its original matlab version:

```
vx = angle(conj(psi1).*psi1(ixp,:,:) ...
                  +conj(psi2).*psi2(ixp,:,:));
```

`psi` are 3d arrays of complex numbers, `ixp` are int arrays

And helper [article](https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots) I wonder about two things:

1. is "`view`" result of same size that psi? If yes then would be the point of `view` here?
2. If not how does this expression unroll in `[i,j,k]` and `for` loop terms?

What have I tried:
I try to translate it into CSharp and got something like this:

```
//fassuming psi are a square
double[,,] vx = new double[psi1.Length,psi1[0].Length,psi1[0][0].Length];

for (int index1 = 0; index1 < psi1.Length; ++index1) {
    for (int index2 = 0; index2 < psi1[index1].Length; ++index2) {
        for (int index3 = 0; index3 < psi1[index1][index2].Length; ++index3) {
            var c1 = Complex.Conjugate(psi1[index1][index2][index3]);
            var c2 = Complex.Conjugate(psi2[index1][index2][index3]);
            var mul1 = psi1[index1][index2][ixp[index3]];
            var mul2 = psi1[index1][index2][ixp[index3]];
            var summ = (c1 * mul1 + c2 * mul2);
            var result = summ.Phase;
            vx[index1, index2, index3] = result;
        }
    }
}
```

now I wonder how far from the correct result I am in my understanding of Julia language.

Comment: Q1:  When you look at the `view` in Julia, what size do you see?

Comment: [Views](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Views-(SubArrays-and-other-view-types)-1) are non-allocating and usually more efficient.

Comment: I see readability pain in form of dots all around it `.*view(psi1, ixp,:,:) .+` because if `ixp` has not the same elements count as `psi` than it will crash...=)

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, in your use of the code, do you find the dimensions of each `view` compatible. I.e., does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` and `.+` do not require its operands to be the same shape. If necessary and there is a match of dimensions, they can broadcast. If, for example, `ixp` is an array with *a single entry*, that line should still evaluate without an error. See the following example:

```
julia> a = rand(1:5, 4, 4, 2)
4×4×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  4  3  5
 2  1  1  1
 3  4  1  2
 3  5  1  3

[:, :, 2] =
 4  4  1  5
 3  4  4  4
 5  3  2  3
 5  3  4  4

julia> a[[1], :, :]
1×4×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  4  3  5

[:, :, 2] =
 4  4  1  5

julia> a .* a[[1], :, :]
4×4×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  16  9  25
 2   4  3   5
 3  16  3  10
 3  20  3  15

[:, :, 2] =
 16  16  1  25
 12  16  4  20
 20  12  2  15
 20  12  4  20

julia> a .* a[[1,1,1,1], :, :] # should give the same results as the prev. command
4×4×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  16  9  25
 2   4  3   5
 3  16  3  10
 3  20  3  15

[:, :, 2] =
 16  16  1  25
 12  16  4  20
 20  12  2  15
 20  12  4  20
```

The size of the resulting `view` depends on the indexing argument `ixp`. If `ixp` is of the same size as the size of the first dimension of `psi`, then the resulting view will be the same shape as the `psi` but possibly with different order in the first dimension as `ixp` could be [2,3,4,1] or [2,3,1,1]. If that is the case, then **the behavior is as in your C# code**. The other case where this line should still evaluate without an error is the case where `ixp` is a single entry array and the behavior is as in the above snippet. If `ixp` is a single entry the results will be the same as if that same entry is repeated as many times as the size of the first dimension of `psi` (as in the last command of snippet above.)  So since you implemented the first case, the behavior in the other case(single `ixp` entry) can also be implemented easily.

In other sizes of `ixp`, there should be an error due to `DimensionMismatch`.

Your C# code seems to be correctly implementing the behaviour in the first case.

If you are trying to translate this Julia project into another language, then it would help if you have more information about the underlying problem maybe `ixp` should always be the same size as the size of `psi` in the first dimension. Examining the samples and the other code in that Github repository, I think that's the case. `ixp` is used only to change the order of `psi`'s first dimension. Even if it is not, there is not a big problem since there are only two viable cases as mentioned above.